# Hibernate custom sql to get last insert id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

how can I return auto-generate id of a newly inserted row using custom sql and value object method (without save/update etc.). Id's (Identity Fields) are handled by the database server.

Java code DatabaseObject.java

```
public int insert(String sql, Object valueObject) throws Exception {
    Session session = Entitlement.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    int result = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
            .setProperties(valueObject).executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return result;
}
```

Using DatabaseObject

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user(emailAddress, password) VALUES(:emailAddress, :password)";
UserVO valueObject = new UserVO("test@email.com", "pass1234");
databaseObject.insert(sql, valueObject);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public BigInteger insert(String sql, Object valueObject) throws Exception
{
    Session session = Entitlement.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();

    session.createSQLQuery(sql)
           .setProperties(valueObject)
           .executeUpdate();

    BigInteger result = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
                               .uniqueResult();

    txn.commit();
    session.close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks @eggyal. How to deal with concurrency issue in this example if you've several hundred threads executing the same function

Comment: @user2727195: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is maintained *per database connection*.

Comment: ok, I understand now. also we found that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is a user session specific function, tested with a dummy insert in mysql workbench and both values are different.

Comment: Can this be problematic with connection pooling (c3p0)?